# How do I solve Vb or Ib of a bjt with a base transistor?

Tags: transistors, bjt, npn

[image]

The problem I run into is I don't know what Vb, Ve, or Vc are.  So I don't know where to turn.  If i knew Vb (or Ve) I would use Vbe = 0.7 to solve the other and then I could solve for the current through one of the resistor legs and I would be on my way.  Please let me know if there is a "fan favorite" practical method of quickly solving this.  Thank you

Comment: Can you try and apply KVL from Vin to ground? Solve that for the base current (or emitter current.)

Answer (score 1):

The transistor will be in only one of three states

- Cut off - I<sub>C</sub> zero
- Saturated - VCE near zero
- Linear - With some finite I<sub>C</sub> and VCE

Make the assumption that the transistor is in one of those states. Now compute all the other values. If the other values are consistent with that state, then your assumption was correct. If not, try one of the others.

In your example, if Vin is less than a typical VBE, then the transistor is cut off (though any finite VBE will give you a finite I<sub>E</sub>, it depends how exact you want to be, a 400mV VBE will give a very very small current for instance).

If Vin is more than a VBE, then assume a transistor with an infinite HFE, so I<sub>B</sub> is zero. Assume a reasonable VBE. Compute the emitter voltage, then the emitter current given R2, then the collector voltage given R3. Are the computed collector and emitter possible, is VCE positive? Yes, it's linear, if you're given HFE then use it, otherwise make a reasonable finite assumption (like 100) for it and recompute. No, it's saturated, recompute using the voltages to determine the currents.